# Java Apache POI: place an image in a specific location

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I need to place an image in a specific location in docx file. I can place an image at any paragraph and even create a new paragraph, but aligning breaks.
I tried to put a placeholder in the document and put my image there. Here is my code:

```
try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(
                Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)));
        ) {
            List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphList = doc.getParagraphs();

            for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : xwpfParagraphList) {
                if (Objects.equals(xwpfParagraph.getText().trim(), "QR")) {
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(qr);
                    XWPFRun qrRun = xwpfParagraph.createRun();
                    qrRun.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "qr", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(120));
                    is.close();
                }
    ...
```

and the output docx looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsWBW.png)

How to place an image at the place, where the `QR` placeholder is located?

Comment: What your code does: It adds the picture in a new text run at the end of the found paragraph. What you seem to want: Remove all runs in found paragraph to make it empty. Then add the picture in a new text run at the end of the found paragraph, which is now empty.

Comment: @AxelRichter Hi, I get your point, but I cannot remove all runs from a found paragraph, because it contains text on right side. I need a way to `edit` the "run" content.

Comment: Then your picture is misleading. I cannot see any text at right side in same paragraph containing the text "QR". And replacing single text runs is very complicated as text might spread over multiple different text runs and it is nearly impossible to determine how and why Word spreads text over text runs. Furthermore the picture then would replace characters. And as the picture height doubtless will be higher as the character height, this will disturb the text flow.

Comment: So the task, to replace a part of text in a paragraph with a picture seems over-complicated to me. There rather should be a placeholder picture which then gets replaced.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, I used the approach of "pre-adding a placeholder picture", then detecting and replacing it. The problem is: the placeholder picture shares a paragraph with some text and when I remove the paragraph containing the placeholder picture and place my new picture there, the text also gets erased. Working with POI library seems too complicated for this simple task. My end goal is to convert the docx to pdf, so I'll probably convert docx -> pdf first (without pic.) and add the picture after.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ok, it turned out that converting a docx to pdf is not a trivial task either... I returned to this problem now. I followed your suggestion and tried to replace a "placeholder image" with new image and now there is a problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198054/java-apache-poi-insert-an-image-infront-the-text

Could you help me with this one, please?

Comment: To replace picture templates in Microsoft Word there is no need to delete them. One simply can replace the the binary content with the new. I have shown an example as answer to your new question.