# Java Apache POI: insert an image "infront the text"

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I have a placeholder image in my docx file and I want to replace it with new image. The problem is - the placeholder image has an attribute "in front of text", but the new image has not. As a result the alignment breaks. Here is my code snippet and the docx with placeholder and the resulting docx.

```
            .......
            replaceImage(doc, "Рисунок 1", qr, 50, 50);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            doc.write(out);
            out.close();
            return out.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    public XWPFDocument replaceImage(XWPFDocument document, String imageOldName, byte[] newImage, int newImageWidth, int newImageHeight) throws Exception {
        try {
            int imageParagraphPos = -1;
            XWPFParagraph imageParagraph = null;
            List<IBodyElement> documentElements = document.getBodyElements();
            for (IBodyElement documentElement : documentElements) {
                imageParagraphPos++;
                if (documentElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                    imageParagraph = (XWPFParagraph) documentElement;
                    if (imageParagraph.getCTP() != null && imageParagraph.getCTP().toString().trim().contains(imageOldName)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (imageParagraph == null) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to replace image data due to the exception:\n"
                        + "'" + imageOldName + "' not found in in document.");
            }
            ParagraphAlignment oldImageAlignment = imageParagraph.getAlignment();

            // remove old image
            boolean isDeleted = document.removeBodyElement(imageParagraphPos);
            // now add new image
            XWPFParagraph newImageParagraph = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun newImageRun = newImageParagraph.createRun();
            newImageParagraph.setAlignment(oldImageAlignment);
            try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(newImage)) {
                newImageRun.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "qr",
                        Units.toEMU(newImageWidth), Units.toEMU(newImageHeight));
            }

            // set new image at the old image position
            document.setParagraph(newImageParagraph, imageParagraphPos);

            // NOW REMOVE REDUNDANT IMAGE FORM THE END OF DOCUMENT
            document.removeBodyElement(document.getBodyElements().size() - 1);

            return document;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to replace image '" + imageOldName + "' due to the exception:\n" + e);
        }
    }
```

The image with placeholder:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZD1.png)

The resulting image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awwg8.png)

Answer (score 2):

To replace picture templates in Microsoft Word there is no need to delete them.

The storage is as so:
The embedded media is stored as binary file. This is the picture data (`XWPFPictureData`). In the document a picture element (`XWPFPicture`) links to that picture data.

The `XWPFPicture` has settings for position, size and text flow. These dont need to be changed.

The changing is needed in `XWPFPictureData`. There one can replace the old binary content with the new.

So the need is to find the `XWPFPicture` in the document. There is a non visual picture name stored while inserting the picture in the document. So if one knows that name, then this could be a criteriea to find the picture.

If found one can get the `XWPFPictureData` from found `XWPFPicture`. There is method `XWPFPicture.getPictureData`to do so. Then one can replace the old binary content of `XWPFPictureData` with the new. `XWPFPictureData` is a package part. So it has `PackagePart.getOutputStream` to get an output stream to write to.

Following complete example shows that all.

The `source.docx` needs to have an embedded picture named "QRTemplate.jpg". This is the name of the source file used while inserting the picture into Word document using Word GUI. And there needs to be a file `QR.jpg` which contains the new content.

The `result.docx` then has all pictures named "QRTemplate.jpg" replaced with the content of the given file `QR.jpg`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordReplacePictureData {
    
 static XWPFPicture getPictureByName(XWPFRun run, String pictureName) {
  if (pictureName == null) return null;
  for (XWPFPicture picture : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
   String nonVisualPictureName = picture.getCTPicture().getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().getName();
   if (pictureName.equals(nonVisualPictureName)) {
    return picture;   
   }
  }
  return null;
 }
 
 static void replacePictureData(XWPFPictureData source, String pictureResultPath) {
  try ( FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(pictureResultPath); 
        OutputStream out = source.getPackagePart().getOutputStream();
       ) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
   int length;
   while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();  
  }
 }
 
 static void replacePicture(XWPFRun run, String pictureName, String pictureResultPath) {
  XWPFPicture picture = getPictureByName(run, pictureName);
  if (picture != null) {
   XWPFPictureData source = picture.getPictureData();
   replacePictureData(source, pictureResultPath);
  }   
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String templatePath = "./source.docx";
  String resultPath = "./result.docx";
  String pictureTemplateName = "QRTemplate.jpg";
  String pictureResultPath = "./QR.jpg";
  
  try ( XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(templatePath));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultPath);
       ) {
   
   for (IBodyElement bodyElement : document.getBodyElements()) {
    if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
     XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
     for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
      replacePicture(run, pictureTemplateName, pictureResultPath);
     }
    }
   }       
   document.write(out);
  }    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a dirty workaround. Since the text block on the right side of the image is static, I replaced the text with screen-shot on the original docx. And now, when the placeholder image been substituted by the new image, everything is rendered as expected.